Why is parity not used to classify topological insulators?
The ten-fold classification of topological insulators employs two distinct symmetries: time reversal and charge conjugation, as well as their combination, known as the sublattice or chiral symmetry. Why is parity not utilized in this classification? Parity corresponds to the spatial counterpart of time reversal, and its absence from the classification seems perplexing.

The ten-fold way classification for periodic topological insulators happened about a decade ago.  It was a big advance for the time.  There have been advances since then.  Lots of symmetries have been looked at beyond the three you mention, as well as disordered crystals, quasicrystals, semimetals, metals, non-hermitian systems, nonlinear systems.  These do not fall under the heading of the ten-fold way.

So is the ten-fold classification obsolete? Because I still read that a certain material fall e.g. within the BDI phase and so on. On the other hand, is there a broader periodic table of 1D topological insulators, using those lacking symmetries e.g. parity?

Not obsolete, just part of the picture.   Have a look at papers on topological quantum chemistry.  I think it is too complicated for a table.
